# Vue transition: v-on:before-leave hides element before callback executes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, velocity.js

I'm learning Vue and very confused about this.

I'm trying to replicate jQuery's `slideToggle()`.

I have a list of items, each with a heading and a body.

Initially the body of each list item is hidden, and when the user clicks the title it should do a slide transition.

Because the body of each list item is a variable height, I need to do this in JS, because CSS can't correctly do the transition for `height: auto`. (Even `max-height` is far from smooth.

So I'm using the Velocity.js library, and `slideDown` is perfect. `slideUp` can't run because (I think) Vue has already hidden the element.

Here's the (simplified) template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="word in saved_definitions">
        <h3 @click="word.show = !word.show">
            {{ word.word }}
        </h3>
        <transition v-on:before-enter="slide_down" v-on:before-leave="slide_up" :css="false">
            <div v-show="word.show">
                {{ word.definition }}
            </div>
        </transition>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`saved_definitions` is an array of `{word: '', definition: '', show: true}` objects.

Here are the relevant methods:

```
slide_down: function(el) {
    Velocity(el, 'slideDown', 'fast');
},

slide_up: function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    Velocity(el, 'slideUp', 'fast');
}
```

`slide_down()` is working perfectly.

`slide_up()` doesn't work, the definition disappears with no transition. The `console.log()` shows that the element has `display: none` before Velocity can do the `slideUp`.

jsFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/zmoc2v3n/ - you can see slideDown is smooth, slideUp doesn't work.

I've tried the `leave` and `after-leave` hooks, which don't help.

And if I use `v-if`, I see the element get rendered first, then hidden, and then slideDown happens. I still have the same issue with `before-leave` hiding the element immediately.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on the [Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-on-before-leave-transition-hides-element-before-callback-runs/8424), and thought I'd post the answer here.

> Try using the enter and leave events instead, as they allow you to let
>   Vue know when your animation is finished.

```
<transition @enter="slide_down" @leave="slide_up"></transition>
```

In the js:

```
function slide_down(el, done) {
    Velocity(el, 'slideDown', {
        duration: 'fast',
        complete: done
    })
}

function slide_up(el, done) {
    Velocity(el, 'slideUp', {
        duration: 'fast',
        complete: done
    })
}
```

Turns out my issue was more with Velocity than Vue.

[Here is the working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/y3p9nzLt/)